# Using new with C++ Constructors that use C malloc

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, new-operator

Can you safely use malloc in the constructor of a C++ class and use new to create instances of that object? I'm aware that it's unsafe to use the two in tandem with each other under normal circumstances, but in this instance is it possible/safe?

Comment: Are you looking for [placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)?

Comment: yes, it works: is your question about some code that could look like: `struct A { int* val; A() : val(malloc(sizeof(int)) {} ~A() { free(val); }; A* = new A;

Comment: I suppose that if the constructor contains a pointer to mallocated memory, and the destructor frees it, then there's no problem with the object that's constructed being allocated with `new`.  It isn't exactly doing things the usual way, but as long as you keep the two sets of memory allocation concerns carefully segregated, you should be OK.  If you're looking to `malloc()` the object as a whole, then you've got problems — you're on a hiding to nothing.

Comment: Sure. This happens when calling C libraries all the time. The C library's init function often does a lot of `malloc` calls, and I called it from a constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes you can, but you should have a strong reason. The `new` operator invokes the constructor which in many ways is just like a regular `class` method. You should also add the `free()` part to the destructor.

   But please note, that if you `malloc()` a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) object the constructor of that object will not be called. I think there are very few reasons to call `malloc()` in a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program: you probably wish to `realloc()` later, which is one reason. But you can always use native [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) objects like [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) containers.
2. It's not unsafe to use the two ways of allocating memory in a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program, you just have to be careful not to `malloc()` something and then `delete` it or `new` something and then `free()` it. But with `malloc()` you ALWAYS have to be careful about many things like it returning `NULL` and `free()`ing the allocated memory so it's not an extra thing.

   Once again, the most dangerous thing you can do is `malloc()` a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) object. Because as I already said, the constructor won't be called.